# How to translate "from a contradiction, to a contradiction"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I am not that familiar with latin, I do confess; Nevertheless, I am trying to translate "From a contradiction, to a contradiction" into Latin. When I do so with a translator, which I would presume (given how wrong they typically are with languages I am comfortable translating on my own and cross-comparing) isn't too reliable. It translates to "ex repugnantia contradictio". Although I am not well versed in Latin, that doesn't seem like it is the same as "from a contradiction, to a contradiction". "repugnantia" seems an awful lot like "repugnance" (in english, although I may be incorrect here), which is typically defined as "a dislike so strong as to cause stomach upset or queasiness". So, in my head, if I try to translate "ex repugnantia contradictio" back to english (broadly speaking, in my head), I think it means more along the lines of "out of a repugnant contradiction" (or maybe "out of a repulsive contradiction"). I think this strips out the **to** aspect of "from a contradiction, to a contradiction": now it is just a repugnant **ex** (out of). Again, I may be just blatantly wrong here, but can anyone help me translate it while retaining the exact underlying meaning?

**UPDATE:**
As requested by Adam, I should probably elaborate on what I am trying to convey. I am, essentially, trying to convey that when the subject extrapolates inwardly, in an effort to explain themselves, and when they extrapolate outwardly, in an effort to explain the objects, they end up with a contradiction: hence "From a contradiction, to a contradiction" (as in, the subject derives themselves, the subject, to a point that inevitably results in a contradiction and when they derive the objects around them--on a macro or micro level--the same occurs). I am going to purposely keep the explanation this brief simply because it is a philosophical position which doesn't directly pertain to this forum. Let me know if anyone requires further exposition on the topic to accurately help me translate it.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's good to question Google Translator as it historically has not been great at translating to and from Latin. What meaning to you want to convey with the phrase? Understanding that can affect which vocabulary best captures the meaning you want.

Comment: @Adam thank you for your response: I updated my question.

Comment: *Repugnare* does indeed mean "to be contradictory, inconsistent, incompatible" (and so does the English word [repugnant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/repugnant)!), so *repugnantia* is probably not a bad choice. The problem with *contradictio* is that it means "objection, counter-argument" (but then so does the English word [contradiction](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contradiction), but that's not the intended meaning here).